# Griffon resource loading differences between run-app and test-app

Tags: file-io, groovy, classloader, griffon

I am fairly new to Griffon and have some experience with Grails.

I have a problem loading a file from the resources directory.

I am using Griffon version 1.4.0.

When I run `griffon run-app` the following code (inside a Service) to get the location of an XML file works fine:

```
URL resource = getResourceAsURL('schema.xsd')
assert resource != null : "schema cannot be located"
```

When I run `griffon test-app` however the same code produces an assertion error because the returned `URL` is null. Same behaviour with `getResourceAsStream()`.

This happens in the **unit test** of said service.

I put the file in `./griffon-app/resources`.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to copy all resources from production to some test resources folder, do I have to edit the build-configuration?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** as suggested below I filed a [bug report](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-646) in the griffon-projects issue tracker.

Comment: what version of griffon?

Comment: I added the Griffon version to my post.

Comment: Where are you calling `getResourceAsURL`? I'm trying to come up with a failing example

Comment: I run it from inside a Service, call the service from it's unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[araxn1d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758470/araxn1d) is correct, running the tests in integration mode will give you the right answer because the full application gets bootstrapped before tests are run. Now, running this kind of test (a unit test that depends on resources being available in the classpath) encounters a problem because the classpath is not setup correctly. Executing the following command

```
griffon -Dgriffon.cli.verbose=true test-app --unit --compileTrace=true
```

will output all classpaths. There you can see that the `resources` directory points to `$USER_HOME/.griffon/1.4.0/projects/<project_name>/resources`. If you inspect that directory you'll find the file you're looking for inside `griffon-app/resources`. This means the test classpath is not accurately configured as it should be `$USER_HOME/.griffon/1.4.0/projects/<project_name>/resources/griffon-app/resources` instead. This is clearly a bug, most likely found in the `$GRIFFON_HOME/scripts/_GriffonClasspath.groovy` script. Could you please file a JIRA http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/griffon ticket for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should run test-app to run your unit tests. In this case you should mock any refers to real files, otherwise you should implement **Integration Tests**. Pls see [Griffon Testing](http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/1.0.0/guide/10.%20Testing.html). **Integration tests differ from unit tests in that you have full access to the Griffon application within the test.**